# Building with Atlassian's Bamboo

Tags: managed-package, package, external-app

I'm trying to use Atlassian's Bamboo service to start using CI development into the company I work for. I have a dummy dev org with a simple App running, but I can't seem to make Bamboo work. The build.xml file is making me go crazy, for real.

I'm getting the following error when trying to build the project:

```
Could not find test result reports in the /home/bamboo/bamboo-agent-home/xml-data/build-dir/TBA-APPKEY-JOB1 directory.

BUILD FAILED
/home/bamboo/bamboo-agent-home/xml-data/build-dir/TBA-APPKEY-JOB1/build.xml:19: Problem: failed to create task or type antlib:com.salesforce:retrieve
Cause: The name is undefined.
Action: Check the spelling.
Action: Check that any custom tasks/types have been declared.
Action: Check that any <presetdef>/<macrodef> declarations have taken place.
No types or tasks have been defined in this namespace yet

This appears to be an antlib declaration. 
Action: Check that the implementing library exists in one of:
        -/opt/ant-1.8/lib
        -/home/bamboo/.ant/lib
        -a directory added on the command line with the -lib argument


Total time: 0 seconds
```

Ok. So the problem is in the .xml file, right? Here it is:

```
<project name="Test BikeApp" default="deployEmptyCheckOnly" basedir=".." xmlns:sf="antlib:com.salesforce">
    <taskdef uri="antlib:com.salesforce"
        resource="com/salesforce/antlib.xml"
        classpath="${basedir}/build/ant-salesforce.jar"/>



    <property file="${basedir}/build/build.properties"/>
    <property environment="env"/>

    <target name="getCode">
      <echo level="info">Retrieving the server's version of code</echo>
      <mkdir dir="${basedir}/${sf.retrieveTarget}"/>
      <sf:retrieve
        retrieveTarget="${basedir}/${sf.retrieveTarget}"
        username="${sf.username}"
        password="${sf.password}"
        serverurl="${sf.serverurl}"
        unpackaged="src/package.xml"/>
      <move file="${basedir}/${sf.retrieveTarget}" tofile="src"/>
    </target>

    <target name="deployCode">
      <echo level="info">Performing the deploy</echo>
      <sf:deploy
        username="${sf.username}"
        password="${sf.password}"
        serverurl="${sf.serverurl}"
        deployRoot="${basedir}/src"
        pollWaitMillis="${sf.pollWaitMillis}"
        maxPoll="${sf.maxPoll}"/>
    </target>

    <target name="deployEmptyCheckOnly">
      <echo level="info">Testing the deploy</echo>
      <sf:deploy
          checkOnly="true"
          logType="Debugonly"
          username="${sf.username}"
          password="${sf.password}"
          serverurl="${sf.serverurl}"
          deployRoot="${basedir}/src"
          pollWaitMillis="${sf.pollWaitMillis}"
          maxPoll="${sf.maxPoll}" 
          runAllTests="true" />
    </target>

</project>
```

I've read Salesforce's documentation regarding the Migration Tool, Ant variables, etc. But I still don't get what can be wrong with this thing. The error I'm getting tells me that "the name is undefined", but what name? The project name? The target name? Both have names, for Christ's sake.

Any ideas?

Comment: How are you trying to set this up? The issue here is definitely that you aren't loading in the ant-salesforce.jar on line 4 of your build xml because it wont exist in the build path. Are you using bitbucket or any other git repos with this?

Comment: I'm using the Atlassian stack (Bitbucket + Bamboo + AWS). I have only one repository for this project at the moment, for testing purposes. As ArtieBrosius mentioned, I'm starting to think my problem is related to the fact that Salesforce's Ant file (the Migration Tool) isn't available by default, and I need to push it to the AWS manually before trying to build anything. This is weird because Atlassian even gave presentations about CI with Salesforce, so I assumed it was already available.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bamboo definitely took me a little while to get configured the way I wanted it when I first started on our CI infrastructure. Hopefully this can help set you on the right course to at least get the base of this working to adapt from there.

First, lets start with your repository where the code that will build exists. The root of your repo should look something like this where the `lib` folder will contain the `ant-salesforce.jar` which will run the actually build, and src is the root of your salesforce metadata. The `build.xml` file will reside at the root as well.

[image]

Your build.xml file should look something like the basic one below, where you are referencing the location of the ant-salesforce.jar in the lib folder, and have targets that will run deploys using the ant-salesforce.jar

```
 <project name="CI-DevMerge" default="deployRunNoTests" basedir="." xmlns:sf="antlib:com.salesforce">
    <taskdef uri="antlib:com.salesforce"
        resource="com/salesforce/antlib.xml"
        classpath="${basedir}/lib/ant-salesforce.jar"/>

<property file="build.properties"/>
<property environment="env"/>
<!-- default deploy runs with tests and no tests -->

<target name="deployRunAllTests">
  <sf:deploy username="${sf.username}" 
    password="${sf.password}" 
    serverurl="${sf.serverurl}" 
    runAllTests="true"
    logType="Detail"
    deployRoot="src"
    maxPoll="${sf.maxPoll}" />
</target>

<target name="deployRunNoTests">
  <sf:deploy username="${sf.username}" 
    password="${sf.password}" 
    serverurl="${sf.serverurl}" 
    runAllTests="false"
    logType="Detail"
    deployRoot="src"
    maxPoll="${sf.maxPoll}" />
</target>
</project>
```

From here, we will assume that you have a full metadata retrieve with a valid package.xml and such located in the src folder of your bitbucket repo. Now lets head over to Bamboo.

I prefer to do my builds on a windows box, because it happens to be more familiar to me, so thats what i will cover here. My Image Config is set to boot up an elastic instance on AWS and mount the Bamboo Windows 2008 stock image. This should give you the actual elastic instance you can run your builds against.

Create a new plan to auto build your changes and go to add a Stage. For your first step, check out the code from the repo in bitbucket. It should look something like this:

[image]

For our second task, we are going to actually run the build.xml and perform the deploy with an Ant Task(I have an intermediate step that cleans up some crap files in the build before it actually builds. ignore that here). Set the Build file to your build.xml. For your target, you would put in the the variables you want to pass to the ant task, as well as tell it which target in the build.xml file to trigger. I set my build jdk for the ant job to 1.7 because that works best so far for me.

[image]

Now for Environmental Variables, we need to actually add the credentials that will be passed to Bamboo to run the build against the target salesforce org. If you use the above files in your build, you need to define SFUSER as the username for the target org, and SFPWD as your password with your security token. Dont put these in quotes or anything. Ex:`SFUSER=myuser@test.com.devbox`. Note that the build will **not** produce test results. If you check that box, your builds will fail by bamboo even if they actually succeed with salesforce.

Once you get this working with a single build, you can have it autorun once you have committed changes to master. A typically CI implementation with git has devs working on separate branches (with the ticket number in them if you use Jira too btw... and the commits) and then creating pull requests to be reviewed by the team prior to merge with Master. If you adapt this structure, trigger the bamboo plan you just made to poll the repository for changes every 2 minutes or so. If it recognizes a change to master, it will run the build and auto build those checked in changes right into your target salesforce box. I have added a pic below of what that config looks like.

[image]

I have a pretty extensive CI implementation in place right now with a setup that sounds very familiar to yours. If you have any additional questions or require any additional clarifications, please feel free to ask and I can update the answer accordingly.

Comment: Thank you for the little tutorial! Although I figured most of this on my own, I discovered the reason of my issue: When I created a new Elastic Instance in Bamboo Administration Panel, Bamboo created the instance but did not provide the keys to access the server (as amazon does when you create in their panel). The solution was to create a keypair called "elasticbamboo" before creating the instance on Bamboo itself, and then I could use it to log into the machine and put the .jar in there.

Comment: If you're using bitbucket, you don't need to upload the jar to your instance. The jar would be part of your source control and would be checked out and within the elastic instance every time your build ran. If you notice in the start of the answer, my jar is in my lib folder in bitbucket. No need to log into the elastic instance at all. Way easier to update the jar itself that way too. When a new version comes out, you just check it into bitbucket instead of messing with your bamboo administration.

Comment: @cricketlang: Can I know how you handled this unwanted crap task. Can you pls share the configuration on this unwanted crap task?

Comment: Could you please share what you have in the 2nd step? 'Remove Unwanted ...' ? I need to strip package of some components but truggling with it

Comment: @AntonSolomin here is a pastebin of a build.xml file that has a few sections where there are various types of cleanup, and some other examples of fun stuff in a build file https://pastebin.com/qEvV9WkV

Answer (score 1):

I had some similar issues when implementing Bamboo for my company. My guess here is that the `ant-salesforce.jar` wasn't properly loaded into context.

Are you explicitly loading it into your execution instance?

Comment: What do you mean by loading it explicitly? My presumption was that the Migration Tool .jar was already part of the Bamboo service. Do I have to upload it to Bamboo? Just to be clear, I'm using the cloud service, not a local instance.

Comment: `ant-salesforce.jar` provides salesforce-specific functionality to ant, and is provided by Salesforce; there's no reason to expect Bamboo to have it pre-loaded.  It is available from your org, go to Setup | Developer | Tools | Force.com Migration Tool.  You'll need to consult the Bamboo docs or Atlassian help if you need assistance loading the jar file.

Comment: But how can I get it into Bamboo, since I'm not running it locally?

Comment: Personally, I keep a separate repo for my ant tools and build.xml that I have Bamboo checkout alongside the codebase. If you don't want to do that though, you could just include the `ant-salesforce.jar` in your codebase repo (in the top-level, next to `src`) and modify your build.xml to look for it there

Answer (score 1):

We, too, are using Bamboo "cloud".  To configure the Migration Tool for Bamboo, you have to first upload it to your AWS instance or EBS volume.  I started by uploading the entire folder containing ant-salesforce.jar to the root of the attached EBS volume on our AWS instance.  Then there are two ways to proceed:

1. add the following line to [EBS root]/bin/customizeInstance.sh to copy the ant-salesforce.jar into $ANT_HOME/lib when the instance starts up.

   `cp $mountLocation/salesforce_ant_31.0/ant-salesforce.jar $ANT_HOME/lib/`
2. Copy the ant-salesforce.jar manually into $ANT_HOME/lib directly.

I've used both methods.  Not sure there's an advantage of one over the other. This makes ant-salesforce.jar available to Ant when it executes.

Also, make sure that $ANT_HOME is set and matches the version of Ant that you have declared in your Bamboo build plan.  In my AWS instance, Bamboo installs both versions 1.8 and 1.9, so I made sure was pointing to Ant 1.9 (in `/opt/ant-1.9`)

Hopefully is the missing piece for you.  I'm happy to help you figure it out.  It took me a long time to figure out how to configure Bamboo, so I know what you're up against.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm going to try this today. From what I've seen, this is **probably** the cause of my issues. Will update here if I succeed.

Comment: I tried your solutions, but couldn't figure out how to even login into my AWS. Well, I did, but some unexpected things happened. First, when Bamboo creates the instance automatically, I can't access it because no private keys are generated to login via SSH. Second, when I create it by myself, Bamboo finds it, but doesn't instantiate any agent to build projects. I'm kinda in a roat without a path now, because I can do absolutely nothing right now. Can you provide a link/tutorial on how to do one of those two steps?

Comment: Sure, yeah, there were a bunch of steps to get it all working.  It's been about 8 months since I did it, so I don't remember every detail, but let me see if I can get you pointed in the right place.

Comment: The most important document is this one: https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BAMBOO/Configuring+elastic+instances+to+use+the+EBS You need to setup an EBS volume and create a snapshot in order to install the Salesforce Ant tool.  Follow all the links on this page to see the answers to your other questions as well (creating an AWS keypair, accessing the instance via SSH, etc.).  At the bottom of this page is an explanation of the customization procedure (the customizeInstance.sh script I described above).  Let me know how it goes.  I did a few more things, but these are the essentials.

Comment: I have read those pages. The problem is that Atlassian forgot to mention that you must create a keypair before creating the instance on Bamboo, and that the keypair must be called 'elasticbamboo'. Once I did this, I could access the server and get the SF Merge Tool in there, and then everything worked.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how to reference the Salesforce Ant tasks in your build.xml file:

```
<project name="Demo" default="deploy" basedir=".">
    <property name="sf.username" value="username"/>
    <property name="sf.password" value="passwordAndSecurityToken"/>
    <property name="sf.serverurl" value="https://login.salesforce.com/"/>
    <path id="ant.additions.classpath">
        <fileset dir="ant" includes="ant-salesforce.jar"/>
    </path>
    <target name="deploy">
        <taskdef
            name="sfdeploy"
            classname="com.salesforce.ant.DeployTask"
            classpathref="ant.additions.classpath"
            />
        <sfdeploy
            username="${sf.username}"
            password="${sf.password}"
            serverurl="${sf.serverurl}"
            deployRoot="src"
            runalltests="true"
            >
        </sfdeploy>
    </target>
</project>
```

This allows a default install of Ant to be used on the build machine and makes the Salesforce tooling part of the project rather than part of the environment.

(We use svn:externals to share a number of Ant tasks including ant-salesforce.jar and other third party libraries between multiple projects.)